# How can I change the speed of spoken words, using CognitiveServices in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I want to save text to mp3, how can I change the speed of the spoken language, using `CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer`?

System:

```
var synth = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer()
synth.Rate = (int)-10;
```

CognitiveServices:

```
var synth = new Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer(config, fileOutput)
//change speed?
```

Comment: mmh, what could be the solution